# Continuously repeat flip animation on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, loops, forms

I have a simple HTML form, with a "Next" button at the bottom which flips the form to the "backSide" which reveals additional input fields. The back side contains a "<- back" button which correctly flips the user to the front side with the vertical flip animation [rotateY(180deg)]. The problem I am having is that once I am back on the fron side, edit information, and hit the "next" button again, I can not get the rotations animation to run again. The information on the back side reveals, however, I can not get the "card flip" animation to work continuously (Only works once per button click). Any sort of modifications to my code would be appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[name='next']").on("click", function() {
    console.log("The NEXT Button Worked!");
    $(".form").css("transform", "rotateY(180deg)");
  })
  $("input[name='back']").on("click", function() {
    console.log("The BACK Button Worked!");
    $(".formFlipAgain").css("transform", "rotateY(180deg)");
  })
});

function showBack() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("backSide").style.display = "block";
  }, 600);
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("frontSide").style.display = "none";
  }, 600);
};

function showFront() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("frontSide").style.display = "block";
  }, 600);
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("backSide").style.display = "none";
  }, 600);
};
```

```css
.form {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 2s;
  -o-transition-duration: 2s;
  transition-duration: 2s;
}
.formFlipAgain {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 2s;
  -o-transition-duration: 2s;
  transition-duration: 2s;
}
#flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: space-between;
}
.formTitle {
  border-bottom: solid red;
}
.form-style-5 {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  max-width: 60%;
  max-height: 82vh;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #f4f7f8;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
}
#form-style-5-Animation {
  animation: slide 3s 1;
}
@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0px, 1000%, 0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0%, 0px);
  }
}
.form-style-5:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.form-style-5 fieldset {
  border: none;
}
.form-style-5 legend {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.form-style-5 label {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.form-style-5 input[type="text"],
.form-style-5 input[type="date"],
.form-style-5 input[type="datetime"],
.form-style-5 input[type="email"],
.form-style-5 input[type="location"],
.form-style-5 input[type="number"],
.form-style-5 input[type="search"],
.form-style-5 input[type="time"],
.form-style-5 input[type="url"],
.form-style-5 select {
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
  padding-left: 2%;
  height: 6%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #e8eeef;
  color: #8a97a0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03) inset;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}
.form-style-5 textarea {
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
  padding-left: 2%;
  height: 12%;
  /*Changing height for task textarea*/
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #e8eeef;
  color: #8a97a0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03) inset;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}
.form-style-5 input[type="text"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="date"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="datetime"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="email"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="number"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="search"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="time"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="location"]:focus,
.form-style-5 textarea:focus,
.form-style-5 select:focus {
  background: #d2d9dd;
}
.form-style-5 select {
  -webkit-appearance: menulist-button;
  height: 35px;
}
.form-style-5 .number {
  background: red;
  color: #FCFBE3;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin-right: 4px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-radius: 0px 15px 15px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}
.form-style-5 input[type="submit"],
.form-style-5 input[type="button"] {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 39px 10px 39px;
  color: #FCFBE3;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: normal;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-width: 1px 1px 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #b30000;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.form-style-5 input[type="backButton"] {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 39px 10px 39px;
  color: #FCFBE3;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: normal;
  width: 140px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-width: 1px 1px 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #b30000;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.form-style-5 input[type="submit"]:active,
.form-style-5 input[type="button"]:active {
  transform: translateY(3px);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #b30000;
}
.form-style-5 input[type="submit"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="button"]:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
.next {
  -webkit-transition-duration: .01s;
  -moz-transition-duration: .01s;
  -o-transition-duration: .01s;
  transition-duration: .01s;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
}
#backSide {
  -moz-transform: scale(-1, 1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
  -o-transform: scale(-1, 1);
  -ms-transform: scale(-1, 1);
  transform: scale(-1, 1);
}
#backButton {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #b30000;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  left: 15px;
  top: 3px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 27px;
  font-size: 105%;
  outline: 0;
}
#name,
#contact,
#location,
#misc,
#job {
  height: 5%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="formFlipAgain">
  <div class="form" id='flex'>
    <div class="form-style-5" id="form-style-5-Animation">
      <div id="frontSide">
        <form action="send-sms.php" method="POST">
          <fieldset>
            <legend>
              <div class="formTitle">Fill out the form below!</div>
            </legend>
            <input type="text" name="field1" id="name" placeholder="Your Name *">
            <input type="text" name="field3" id="location" placeholder="Your Location (i.e. McNutt, exact address, etc.)*">
            <input type="email" name="field2" id="email" placeholder="Email Address">
            <span class="number">or</span>
            <input type="text" name="field5" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
            <textarea type="text" id="task" name="field6" rows="1" placeholder="Task that needs completion, let us know how we can help!*"></textarea>
          </fieldset>
          <input name="next" type="button" value="Next &#x21fe;" class="next" onClick="showBack();" />
      </div>
      <div id="backSide" style="display: none;">
        <input name="back" class="Button" type="button" onClick="showFront();" value="&#x21fd; &nbsp; back" id="backButton" />
        <fieldset>
          <legend>
            <div class="formTitle">Please fill all required fields!</div>
          </legend>
          <input type="text" name="field1" id="name" placeholder="Your Name *">
          <input type="text" name="field3" id="location" placeholder="Your Location (i.e. McNutt, exact address, etc.)*">
          <input type="text" name="field4" id="misc" placeholder="Miscellaneous Information That May Be Important">
          <input type="email" name="field2" id="email" placeholder="Email Address">
          <label for="job">Urgency:</label>
          <select id="job" name="field5">
            <optgroup label="Urgency level: just for us to prioritize properly">
              <option value="Not Urgent">Low (ETA: Up to an hour)</option>
              <option value="reading">Normal (ETA: Up to 45 mins)</option>
              <option value="boxing">Critical (ETA: ASAP!)</option>
            </optgroup>
          </select>
          <input type="text" name="field4" id="misc" placeholder="Miscellaneous Information That May Be Important">
        </fieldset>
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="push();return validateForm();" />
        </fieldset>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to **reset their rotation**.

If it's rotated at 180° and you flip to 180°, it'll stay how it is.